# How do I add an icon to the taskbar for a simple win32 dialog?

Tags: winapi, dialog, icons

I have a very simple app which has a few buttons and text fields.  I want to be able to add an icon to it, as you cant see if it is running when it is behind other windows.  What is the simplest way of doing this?

I tried creating a window which was hidden which kinda works but you can see that other window blink when you click on the taskbar icon and I can't seem to make it focus on the dialog box.

Comment: A top-level unowned window will, by default, have an associated taskbar button. What have you done with your app to stop that happening.

Comment: What I have is a basic WinMain which calls RegisterClassEx/CreateWindowEx.  Once this is created I then show my dialog box which is created using VS resource editor.  I can get it to show the icon, but clicking on the icon doesn't minimize/maximize the dialog box, instead it does that on the window created with CreateWindowEx

Comment: What you are expected to do is use the window you create with `CreateWindowEx` as your application's main window. Why are you using a dialog box as your main window? That seems to be the problem.

Comment: I just want to use the resource editor to create my GUI.  Can I use this window in CreateWindowEx?

Comment: I've added an answer that explains my understanding of how you should tackle this. Essentially you need to make the dialog be the only top level window in your app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the fundamental problem is that you have a hidden top-level window which owns your dialog. The dialog is acting as the main window, but the taskbar shows a button associated with the hidden window.

So I guess what you need to do is remove the hidden window altogether. That means getting rid of the `RegisterClass` and `CreateWindow` calls.

I'm assuming you show the dialog modeless. In which case you use CreateDialog and ShowWindow to show it. Take heed particularly of this section of the documentation:

> After CreateDialog returns, the application displays the dialog box (if it is not already displayed) by using the ShowWindow function. The application destroys the dialog box by using the DestroyWindow function. To support keyboard navigation and other dialog box functionality, the message loop for the dialog box must call the IsDialogMessage function.

Of course if you are showing the dialog modally you can probably carry on doing that. In which case your `WinMain` function is very simple. It's just a call to `DialogBox`. No message loop needed because the modal dialog's message loop handles the messages.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works a treat!  For some reason I had it in my head that I needed to use CreateWindowEx to get my message loop.  I just removed the code to RegsiterClassEx/CreateWindowEx and added the IsDialogMessage to the message loop and it now all works.  My PlayList creator is now complete with a separate thread so that the GUI always remains responsive :)

Comment: @allanmb: If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting and upvoting it so others who view this post can find it helpful **more easily**. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended window style to your dialog. In this case task bar application button will show up even if dialog's owner/parent window is hidden.